# Install Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web parallel to Visual Studio Professional 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Can I install **Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web** parallel to my installed **Visual Studio Professional 2010**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) on VS2012 side by side installations may help.  It states:

> You can install this version of Visual Studio on a computer that
>   already has an earlier version installed.

As long as you install them in the correct order, and note the conditions, I think you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I hope this also applies to the Express editions... :-)

Comment: @Ollie: Did it apply to the Express edition?